# Undefined symbol when loading shared library in Python

Tags: python, c++, linker, shared-libraries, .so

I try to use a shared library written in C++ inside some python code. I'm under Linux OS.

Firstly I create the shared library using the following commands:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -c HeliosDacAPI.cpp
g++ -shared -o libHeliosDacAPI.so HeliosDacAPI.o
```

Then I try and load this library inside the python console:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> HeliosLib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./libHeliosDacAPI.so")
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 425, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 347, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: ./libHeliosDacAPI.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9HeliosDac18GetControlResponseEiPhi
```

---

Here is [HeliosDacAPI.h](https://github.com/Grix/helios_dac/blob/master/sdk/HeliosDacAPI.h)

`nm libHeliosDacAPI.so` shows:

```
0000000000202088 B __bss_start
0000000000202088 b completed.7585
                 w __cxa_finalize@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000202090 B dacController
0000000000000cb0 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000000d40 t __do_global_dtors_aux
0000000000201dd8 t __do_global_dtors_aux_fini_array_entry
0000000000202078 d __dso_handle
0000000000202080 d DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0
0000000000201de8 d _DYNAMIC
0000000000202088 D _edata
00000000002020a0 B _end
00000000000014b8 T _fini
0000000000000d80 t frame_dummy
0000000000201dd0 t __frame_dummy_init_array_entry
0000000000001758 r __FRAME_END__
0000000000202000 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
00000000000014dc r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
                 U __gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3
0000000000000bb0 T _init
0000000000202098 B inited
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000201de0 d __JCR_END__
0000000000201de0 d __JCR_LIST__
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
                 U __printf_chk@@GLIBC_2.3.4
0000000000000cf0 t register_tm_clones
                 U __stack_chk_fail@@GLIBC_2.4
0000000000202088 d __TMC_END__
                 U _Unwind_Resume@@GCC_3.0
0000000000001230 T _Z10SetShutterib
0000000000000db0 T _Z10WriteFrameiihP11HeliosPointi
0000000000001420 T _Z11OpenDevicesv
00000000000013d0 T _Z12CloseDevicesv
0000000000001360 T _Z13EraseFirmwarei
0000000000001290 T _Z18GetFirmwareVersioni
0000000000000f20 T _Z4Stopi
0000000000000f90 T _Z7GetNameiPc
00000000000010c0 T _Z7SetNameiPc
0000000000001150 T _Z9GetStatusi
                 U _ZdlPv@@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZN9HeliosDac11OpenDevicesEv
                 U _ZN9HeliosDac11SendControlEiPhi
                 U _ZN9HeliosDac18GetControlResponseEiPhi
                 U _ZN9HeliosDac9SendFrameEiPhi
                 U _ZN9HeliosDacC1Ev
                 U _ZN9HeliosDacD1Ev
                 U _Znwm@@GLIBCXX_3.4
```

I'm looking for some tips on how to debug such problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot be sure, but it seems that `HeliosDac::GetControlResponse(int, ?*, int)` is defined in `HeliosDac.cpp` which you do not compile and link into `libHeliosDacAPI.so`.

Indeed, from `nm libHeliosDacAPI.so` we clearly see that this symbol is used but `U`ndefined (this implies that your problem doesn't come from your way to load the library from python):

```
                 U _ZN9HeliosDac18GetControlResponseEiPhi
```

You could try to compile with:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -c HeliosDacAPI.cpp
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -c HeliosDac.cpp
g++ -shared -lusb -o libHeliosDacAPI.so HeliosDacAPI.o HeliosDac.o
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the actual problem, or link to some place with more information ? I'm having a related "undefined symbol" problem, but I can't find a way to generalize this answer. Posting this here because this page showed on top googling a variant of "python loading library undefined symbol".

Comment: @JaccovanDorp here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5470596

Comment: So, if I got it correct, there's either another shared object/DLL that you're missing, or the shared object/DLL was compiled incorrectly. Got it.